# How can I exit Bash from Vim?

Tags: command-line

Can Vim kill its parent process?

I know a child could not kill a parent process in Linux, but how can I achieve `:!exit` in Vim?

I would like to exit directly from Vim out of the terminal without semi-step of exiting Vim first. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you start Vim as `exec vim` then it will replace the shell process with the Vim one, so when you quit Vim there is nothing left and the terminal will close. I'm not sure if I 100% follow your question, but I think this is what you want?

Comment: @MartinTournoij so, but no. My purpose is to close terminal upon `:!exit`, because you exit from terminal when you issue `$exit` command. The same I want to achieve from vim

Comment: What do you want to happen to Vim when you run `:!exit`? Do you want to exit that too, or keep it running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible directly from Vim. This is something that has to be done in the calling shell.

You could work with a shell function:

```
# Vim and optional exit
ve()
{
    vim "$@" || exit
}
```

If Vim returns a non-zero exit code, the command `exit` is called to exit the shell and hence close the terminal.

To produce a non-zero exit code use `:cq` instead of `:q`. If Vim would return a non-zero exit code for any other reason, the terminal would also close.

BTW: Your `:!exit` can't work, as it is not executed in the shell started by the terminal emulator, but in a shell started by vim.

Comment: What does :c do anyway? Cannot find in `:help :c`

Comment: @Herdsman See `:h :cq`.

Answer (score 3):

@Martin Tournoij has the best answer so far. If you edit your .bashrc and add :

```
alias V='exec vim'
```

Then when you start vim with 'V [filename]' the terminal will close when you exit vim. If you start vim with 'vim [filename]' then the terminal will not close when vim exits.